# Handling Null values in GetSQLDateTime and GetSQLMoney

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

AS part of an import I'm writing I'm using parameterised values, however the database i'm exporting to cannot handle NULL values, so I need to find a way to handle NULL values.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
if (tenantexportReader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToDecimal().Equals(null))
{
     tenantimportCommand.Parameters["PRICEFINAL"].Value = "0.00";
} 
else 
{
     tenantimportCommand.Parameters["PRICEFINAL"].Value = tenantexportReader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToDecimal();
}
```

and A similar thing with SQLDateTime

```
if (tenantexportReader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString().Equals(null))
{
    tenantimportCommand.Parameters["TENSDATE"].Value = "0.00";
}
else
{
     tenantimportCommand.Parameters["TENSDATE"].Value = tenantexportReader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString();
}
```

However this does not appear to work, instead I receive the following:

> Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (tenantexportReader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToDecimal().Equals(null))
```

you should probably use

```
if (tenantexportReader.IsDbNull(8))
```

Since the value in the database is NULL (which is `DbNull.Value` in c#), I assume that `GetSqlMoney` and `GetSqlDateTime` throw the exception you received. `DbNull.Value` cannot be converted to `SqlMoney` or `DateTime`.
Check if the value is null via `IsDbNull` before calling `GetSqlMoney` or `GetSqlDateTime`.

---

So your final `if` statements should look something like this:

```
if (tenantexportReader.IsDbNull(8))
{
     tenantimportCommand.Parameters["PRICEASK"].Value = "0.00";
} 
else 
{
     tenantimportCommand.Parameters["PRICEFINAL"].Value = tenantexportReader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToDecimal();
}
```

Comment: That seemed to resolve that particular issue, however it has thrown up a datatype mismatch error instead now.

Comment: @JoshuaCameron-Mackintosh just realized that you use two different parameter names here: `PRICEASK` and `PRICEFINAL`. Is that correct? Can't help you with the datatype mismatch error, especially since I don't know _where_ this is thrown. You may want to open a new question for that and include code and stack trace.

Comment: It was accidental, the parameters have been corrected in the program, but the same error.

Comment: As said before, to get help, you need to show the relevant code and the _complete_ exception including stack trace, ideally even your database scheme and content (the relevant snippets). So if you get a new error, please open a new question including all this information.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you assign a string to a monetary value???

Probably what you would want to do is like this:

```
var priceFinal = tenantexportReader.GetSqlMoney(8);

tenantimportCommand.Parameters["PRICEFINAL"].Value = (decimal)(priceFinal.IsNull ? 0 : priceFinal);
```

I really don't understand why you set it to "0.00" (string) when it is null and to a decimal value when it is not null.

And also for date/datetime values, again, why do you ever use string conversions and invite errors? Simply pass a date as a datetime.